# Is there an efficient .NET collection for fast retrieval operations based on two dimensions ranges?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, search, canvas

I'm looking for a fast and efficient .NET collection (if any). My purpose is to perform for fast range based retrieval operations but that still manage to be not that slow regarding insertions and deletions (I know this is usually the tradeoff about the retrieval efficiency and modifications over collections). To make it short, let's say that retrieval operations efficiency still matter a bit more than the modifications one.

The background is that I'm designing a Canvas using winforms, to make it simple say that I'm just "painting" shapes on it:

[image]

To make the approach a bit simpler, let's consider that no matter how the shape is or looks like, we just are going to consider the bounding box around it defined with a Client Rectangle.

Anyway, say now I'm clicking on an item on my Control (so displayed in the Canvas View) which displays potentially (accordingly to the ZoomValue) only a partial collection of the all the items contains in the Canvas, how to know quickly which item has been clicked?

Each item has its own BoundingBox property (so X, Y, Width & Height) and the Z-order. 
But here it's different we basically have the coordinates of the mouse converted into Canvas View coordinates (accordingly to the zoom factor), and based on it I'm wondering how to avoid a full and lengthy search among the View Items (by the way this question also involves the redistribution of the items when the View is changing).

In case of hundred items it's still fine now I'm thinking about the situation where there is like thousands of arrows on screen (which is a number far more bigger than the one given for the window handle controls and that is why I am designing my own canvas).

I looked at some SPT strategies including the OmniTree data structure which may be the data-structure that is the most suitable to my situation but still, I'm doubting a bit about the modifications than can be pretty slow: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/794171/Omni-Tree-Data-Structure-in-Csharp

Anyone who would have already got the same sort of requirements?

Comment: A simple `List<SimilarToRectangleStructure>` might do well enough. Iterations and hit-tests (e.g. [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02.aspx)) are going to take very little time compared to actual rendering. Another thing is grouping, instead of drawing many figures consisting of overlapped primitives you may want to process that figure first into a simplified figure which doesn't have overlapped parts.

Comment: @Sinatr actually my current dummy implementation is already using lists, basically one list for the whole canvas and another one used by the View just for the rendering / painting process.
I think the problem is that the 'Contains(...)' method might a bit slow when there is a lot shapes (the rendering process result can be cached (as bitmap), so this is not really a problem here). The retrieval operation can be slow since we need to check whether the test hit point is contained among many rectangle, this can take some time.

Comment: @Sinatr that's why I was looking for an alternative way of performing retrieval operations. I was more thinking about a fast and quick balancing tree behind the scenes which allows to work with intervals in both dimensions: x & y.

Comment: You can have a `List<Shape>` which the shape has `ZIndex` Property and `bool HitTest(x,y)` and then `clickedShape=list.Where(s=>s.HitTest(x,y)).OrderBy(s=>s.ZIndex).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @RezaAghaei not efficient when there is a lot of shapes ;-)
I have already done that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not built in collection that allows to search by ranges/bounding rectangles. You'd need to write your own/find library that suits you needs.

There is no generic algorithm that is suited for broad number of applications that will deal with search though range data. Multiple dimensions does not help either.

You may want to look into algoritms used in games:

- [Binary space partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)
- [Bin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_(computational_geometry)) - regular/irregular hash of the space - each rectangle will map to one or many cells
- Your grouping may be a natural solution for search - find rectangle of root and thus limit next level of searches.

Comment: Alright then, need to invent the wheel then :-)
Seems the appropriate answer for me.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just to let people know that I also got pretty good performances using the stuff below:
- A bin using a KD Trees instead of the LinkedLists
- A QuadTree

Comment: R Tree* as well =]

Answer (score 0):

You should use datatables for this purpose, a datatable permit you to find, delete insert and update quickly.